# Validation and getting everything to write to file

Tags: python, loops, validation, writetofile

So I'm working on a password program that logs all incorrect attempts (just the date and time with an error message saying why)
The issue I'm having is when I input a password that is say, >10 and then input a password that is <6...all failed attempts will be logged as >10 even if that isn't the case.

I'm very much a beginner to Python so feel free to explain everything to me like I'm 5.

```
import datetime


def main():

    MIN_LENGTH = 6
    MAX_LENGTH = 10
    PASSWORD_LOG_FILE = "password_log.txt"
    password = input("Please enter your password for checking: ")
    password_length = len(password)


    while len(password) < 6 or len(password) > 10:
        print("Invalid")
        error_log = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        output_file = open(PASSWORD_LOG_FILE, "a")
        output_file.write(error_log)
        password = input("Please enter your password for checking: ")
        if password_length < MIN_LENGTH:
            output_file.write("{}, password <6".format(error_log))
        elif password_length > MAX_LENGTH:
            output_file.write("{}, password >10".format(error_log))
        output_file.write("\n")
        output_file.close()

    if password.isnumeric() is True:
        comment = "password is weak - contains only numbers."
    elif password.isalpha() is True:
        comment = "password is weak - contains only letters."
    else:
        comment = "password is strong."

    print("Your password is {:} characters long".format(len(password)))
    print("Your {:s}".format(comment))

    input_file = open(PASSWORD_LOG_FILE, "r")

    for line in input_file:
        print(line, end='')

    input_file.close()

main()
```

I realise an issue may be in the "While" loop and tried moving bits of code around and re-formatting but I either trigger an endless loop or the error message doesn't begin in a new line etc.
As mentioned above, What I would like to happen is that it tells me the password was invalid because it was either <6 or <10. Right now it logs all incorrect attempts as the same as the first attempt - I can't seem to locate the dodgy line of code that is causing this!

Comment: After you ask the user to re-enter the password, you don't update the `password_length` variable -- it's still the length of the first password they entered.

Comment: Just seeing Barmar's comment - they are correct and my answer is essentially a longer version of this comment.

Comment: Ah of course, now I see what I've done. What a simple mistake! Thankyou both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store `password_length` once at the start, and use it in your `if` check. However, `len(password)` is not the same as `password_length`! You correctly use `len(password)` in your while loop, but you don't update `password_length` to the new length after you retype a password.

You have a few options of how to fix this, but I think the easiest one may be to add the line `password_length = len(password)` just after `password = input("Please enter your password for checking: ")`.

Comment: Thankyou for explaining it to me! (and to Barmar too). That was a quick and easy fix for sure. I can't wait to get better at this, like you guys, so I can easily recognise errors like this. I can't 'upvote' this answer as I don't have enough reputation I'm afraid.

Comment: If you want to speed up recognition rather than having to post every time, ChatGPT can be a really helpful tool! [I copy/pasted your question into it and it got the answer correct](https://chat.openai.com/share/e285c172-42f1-4e42-a1d2-850a56d06e80). It's not always right, but it may give you answers faster, and you can also ask it for debugging tips.